# Android Parse.com query relation

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a custom Employee table and custom Organization table.
Employee table has a column Relation< Organization >.
I want to query organizations of an employee object.

```
// I have an employee object
ParseObject employee = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseObject("employee");
// I get relation query
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = employee.getRelation("organizations").getQuery();
// I execute query like this
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            // code here
        });
```

In my callback I'm getting ClassCastException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
        at com.parse.ParseRESTQueryCommand.constructParameters(ParseRESTQueryCommand.java:84)
        at com.parse.ParseRESTQueryCommand.findCommand(ParseRESTQueryCommand.java:15)
        at com.parse.ParseDefaultQueryController.findFromNetworkAsync(ParseDefaultQueryController.java:57)
        at com.parse.ParseDefaultQueryController.access$100(ParseDefaultQueryController.java:17)
        at com.parse.ParseDefaultQueryController$6.runOnNetworkAsync(ParseDefaultQueryController.java:193)
        at com.parse.ParseDefaultQueryController.runCommandWithPolicyAsync(ParseDefaultQueryController.java:292)
        at com.parse.ParseDefaultQueryController.findWithCachePolicyAsync(ParseDefaultQueryController.java:201)
        at com.parse.ParseDefaultQueryController.findAsync(ParseDefaultQueryController.java:28)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery.findAsync(ParseQuery.java:1187)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery$2$1.then(ParseQuery.java:1129)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery$2$1.then(ParseQuery.java:1125)
        at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
        at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
        at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
        at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
        at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
        at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:574)
        at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:690)
        at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:680)
        at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:714)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery$2.call(ParseQuery.java:1125)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery$2.call(ParseQuery.java:1122)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery.doWithRunningCheck(ParseQuery.java:1091)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery.findInBackground(ParseQuery.java:1122)
```

What am I doing wrong? This is done exactly like in Parse tutorial (https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations-using-parse-relations). I didn't find any answer to this on Google or SOF.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: And you are 100% positive that when looking at the employee class in the data browser, that 'organizations' is not of type string?

Comment: @cYrixmorten 1000% positive. It's a type of Relation<Organization>. Check it out http://take.ms/CZTPR

Comment: I see.. Strange .. can you see at which exact line the error occur from within your code? Just thinking if it might be happening somewhere within your omitted code perhaps

Comment: @cYrixmorten The thing is I didn't omit any code - this is all the code that is needed to do the query. The error occurs somewhere in Parse library where it cannot do the casting, but I don't have an idea where or why

Comment: @cYrixmorten You where right, I did omit how I get an employee object and it seems this was the problem. I did it using ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseObject("employee"). In this case I'm getting an exception. But if I obtain employee object from Parse like this ParseQuery.getQuery("Employee").get("CITLvyOFuK") - relations then work correctly. Do you why can it be so? And is is possible to do 1 request to get organizations, not 2 (get employee, find his organizations)?

Comment: First question: `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseObject("employee")` will not by default return the employee object, only the pointer. Should work if you ´fetch()´ your user before calling `getParseObject()`. Second question: if you switch to use an array of pointers instead of a relation you can do something like `ParseQuery.getQuery("Employee").get("CITLvyOFuK") .include("organizations")`. The return object will contain a Employee object where the list of organizations is populated with data, e.g. `employee.getList("organizations").get(0).getString("name")` will work

Comment: @cYrixmorten Thank you for the answer! Now I get what the problem was. The only question I have - what is the difference between using relation and array of pointers? Is one of the approaches better? In my situation Employee-Organization is in many-to-many relatioship, where 1 employee can have small amount of organizations (not more than 5 I suppose), whereas 1 organization can have thousands of employees.

Comment: A relation is great if you expect a lot (100+) pointers. This way avoiding to fetch a lot of data for every employee. In your case I see no reason for not simply using an array of organizations.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Thank you again, Morten. You can copy your comment to answer section and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From comment by @cYrixmorten**

`ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseObject("employee")` will not by default return the employee object, only the pointer. 
Should work if you `fetch()` your user before calling `getParseObject()`.

If you switch to use an array of pointers instead of a relation you can do something like `ParseQuery.getQuery("Employee").get("CITLvyOFuK").include("organizations")`. The return object will contain a Employee object where the list of organizations is populated with data, e.g. `employee.getList("organizations").get(0).getString("name")` will work.

A relation is great if you expect a lot (100+) pointers. This way avoiding to fetch a lot of data for every employee. In your case I see no reason for not simply using an array of organizations.

**And a note from me**

If you want to add array of pointers in Parse Data Browser use this pattern:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"CLASSNAME","objectId":"OBJECTID"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"CLASSNAME","objectId":"OBJECTID"}]
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to get back to you with an answer made up of the comments. You can just mark this as correct :)

Comment: By the way, if you are adding to an array from android, you can simply do `employee.add("organizations", organization)`. Assuming `organization` is a ParseObject, it will result in a correctly formatted pointer e.g. `{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Organization","objectId":"OBJECTID"}`

Answer (score 0):

here's how you do it. survey being the header record with hearaboutusID as the key field in survey linking to hearaboutus table which is a relation.

```
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("survey");
    try {
        query.include("hearaboutus");
        poSurvey = query.get(<objectID>);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> qry = poSurvey.getRelation("hearaboutusID").getQuery();
    qry.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> hearList, ParseException e) {
            for(ParseObject hear : hearList){                   
                Log.d("HEAR ABOUT US ITEM: ", hear.getObjectId());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4h2to1cdbx087b/SAmpleApp.zip?dl=0 try this i have done similar few weeks back whole src code is in it,you might are gonna need few libraries to run it....hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, but I've searched though all sources and didn't find any relational queries there